# Does local cohomology commute with taking the degree-zero component?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

Let $S = \oplus_{d \geq 0} S_d$ be a graded (Noetherian) ring, let $I \subset S$ be a homogeneous ideal, and let $f \in S$ be a homogeneous element.  Denote by $S_{(f)}$ the subring of degree-$0$ elements of the localization $S_f$.

> Do we always have $(H^i_{IS_f}(S_f))_0 \simeq H^i_{IS_f \cap S_{(f)}}(S_{(f)})$ as $S_{(f)}$-modules? That is, is the degree-zero component of local cohomology the same as local cohomology with respect to the degree-zero components?

More generally, if $S$ is a graded ring and $J \subset S$ a homogeneous ideal, do we have $(H^i_J(S))_0 \simeq H^i_{J_0}(S_0)$ as $S_0$-modules?

The very thorough chapters on graded local cohomology in Brodmann and Sharp's book don't address this, unless I missed it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your more general question is indeed positive. This (and its generalisation to $\mathbb{Z}^n$-graduations and to arbitrary degrees) is proven in Lemma 14.1.12 in the second edition of the book by Brodmann and Sharp (*Local cohomology (second edition),* Cambridge University Press, 2013) mentioned in the question.